# Help with context free grammar excercise

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

So, I have an exercise in which I have to write a context free grammar for this language:

$$L = \{x \in L(a^∗b^∗c^∗) : |x|_a > |x|_c; |x|_b > 0; |x|_c ≥ 0\}$$

meaning every string with any number of $a$'s, $b$'s and $c$'s in that order, with the amount of $a$'s greater than the amount of $c$'s and the amount of $b$'s greater than zero.

I am having trouble figuring out the rule that makes sure there are more $a$s than $c$s.

I have:
$$\begin{align}S&\to aABC | ab\\
A&\to aA | a\\
B&\to bB | b\\
C&\to cC | c\\
\end{align}$$
I know this is wrong because I should be adding an $a$ every time I add a $c$, but I don't know how to write that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in this way

$$\begin{align}
X&\to A\ |\ aXc\ |\ aAc\\
A&\to aA_t\\
A_t&\to aA_t\ |\ B\\
B&\to bB_t\\
B_t&\to bB_t\ |\ \epsilon\\
\end{align}$$

Here $X$ can choose to do the first transformation, if there are not going to be any $c$s. $X$ can do the second transformation many times to add an initial chunk of the same amount of $a$s and $c$s, or do the third transformation to put a last pair of an $a$ and a $c$.

In that third case, it goes to $A$ which puts one extra $a$ and goes to $A_t$, which can put even more $a$s or go to put $b$s.

Then $B$ puts one $b$ and goes to $B_t$, which puts as many more $b$s as wanted or terminates.

But check it. This is the first ever context free grammar rules that I write in my life.

---

Shorter rules by *nir shahar*

$$
\begin{align}
S&\to AB\ |\ aSc\\
A&\to aA\ |\ a\\
B&\to bB\ |\ b
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This seems correct, however you can shorten the grammer.

Comment: I have submitted an edit request :)

Comment: @nirshahar And it looks like that is the smallest.

Comment: "shortest" is such a red flag :-) $$S\to T\mid aSc\\ T\to a\mid aT\mid Tb$$.

Comment: Colleagues: what about strings that mix $a$'s and $c$'s, like $acacaca$?

Comment: @Hendrik: OP says $x\in L(a^∗b^∗c^∗)$. So they're not in the language

Comment: @rici Thanks. Missed that.

Comment: To pass this to a PDA, I have to convert the CFG to GNF and then follow the steps of the algorithm, right? Or is there an easier way?

Comment: @rici $S\Rightarrow T\Rightarrow a$. However, $a$ is not in the language. Rule $T\to a$ should have been $T\to ab$ instead.

Comment: @johnl: alas, one symbol longer. Quite right.